# Cache Expiration in Key level using ABP

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We can store multiple keys under one cache, is it possible to set expiration for key level rather than cache level in ABP?

**MyCache**

1. Key1
2. Key2
3. Key3

I need to set different expiration time for **MyCache** and **Key1**, **Key2**, **Key3**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set sliding expire time when you set the cache. See 
**slidingExpireTime** parameter.

```
/// <param name="key">Key</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value</param>
    /// <param name="slidingExpireTime">Sliding expire time</param>
    /// <param name="absoluteExpireTime">Absolute expire time</param>
    void Set(string key, object value, TimeSpan? slidingExpireTime = null, TimeSpan? absoluteExpireTime = null);
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Runtime/Caching/ICache.cs